# llenar combobox automaticamente al introducir un dato

Tags: java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

buenas noches tengo el siguiuente formulario que esta con una base de datos para mostrar los datos y lo que quiero es poder que llenen los combox automaticamente y poderlos guardar en otra base de datos hay alguna forma de hacerlo gracias

Comment: Por lo que entiendo es que quieres que tu combBox se automcomplete y esos datos se envién automaticamente a una base de datos sin ejecutar ningun accion/evento como un boton de submit?

Comment: Si y poderlo guardar los datos en una base de datos

Comment: Pero otra pregunta los datos los traigo al combo desde una base de datos pero lo que no se si se puede esos datos guardarlos en otra base cuando el usuario llene los datos